# how to open (doc, ppt, xlsx, pdf, jpg ,png) file using ionic native file opener

Tags: angular, file, ionic3

i am developing Hybrid app using ionic. i want to open (doc, ppt, xlsx, pdf, jpg ,png)  file from device internal or external storage using ionic native file opener plugin, but i'm able to open only pdf file using below code. i use **application/pdf** to open pdf, to open other files what shoud i replace at the place of **application/pdf**?
please help me.
thank you.

```
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

constructor(private fileOpener: FileOpener) { }

...

this.fileOpener.open('path/to/file.pdf', 'application/pdf')
  .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error openening file', e));
```

Comment: See https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

finally i got solution.

```
let fileExtn=file_name.split('.').reverse()[0];
let fileMIMEType=this.getMIMEtype(fileExtn);
         this.fileOpener.open("file:///storage/emulated/0/download/"+ file_name+"", fileMIMEType)
                .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
                .catch(e => console.log('Error openening file', e));
```

make other function for MIMEtype

```
getMIMEtype(extn){
  let ext=extn.toLowerCase();
  let MIMETypes={
    'txt' :'text/plain',
    'docx':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    'doc' : 'application/msword',
    'pdf' : 'application/pdf',
    'jpg' : 'image/jpeg',
    'bmp' : 'image/bmp',
    'png' : 'image/png',
    'xls' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlsx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'rtf' : 'application/rtf',
    'ppt' : 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'pptx': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
  }
  return MIMETypes[ext];
}
```

Comment: sir its not working for me i got file not found message and my file format is docx and i got file not found message in console?

Comment: Please make sure you have set file path and file name correctly. Here in above example file path is "file:///storage/emulated/0/download/"  you should change as your path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made a `file-extension.ts` file in my provider folder having a good handful of extensions along with it's appropriate headers . Below is it's code(taken from [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types), see [here for full reference](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)):

**file-extension.ts:**

```
export const FILE_EXTENSION_HEADERS = {
    'aac' : 'audio/aac',
    'abw' : 'application/x-abiword',
    'arc' : 'application/x-freearc',
    'avi' : 'video/x-msvideo',
    'azw' : 'application/vnd.amazon.ebook',
    'bin' : 'application/octet-stream',
    'bmp' : 'image/bmp',
    'bz' : 'application/x-bzip',
    'bz2' : 'application/x-bzip2',
    'csh' : 'application/x-csh',
    'css' : 'text/css',
    'csv' : 'text/csv',
    'doc' : 'application/msword',
    'docx' : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    'eot' : 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject',
    'epub' : 'application/epub+zip',
    'gif' : 'image/gif',
    'htm' : 'text/html',
    'html' : 'text/html',
    'ico' : 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
    'ics' : 'text/calendar',
    'jar' : 'application/java-archive',
    'jpeg' : 'image/jpeg',
    'jpg' : 'image/jpeg',
    'js' : 'text/javascript',
    'json' : 'application/json',
    'jsonld' : 'application/ld+json',
    'mid' : 'audio/midi',
    'midi' : 'audio/midi',
    'mjs' : 'text/javascript',
    'mp3' : 'audio/mpeg',
    'mpeg' : 'video/mpeg',
    'mpkg' : 'application/vnd.apple.installer+xml',
    'odp' : 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation',
    'ods' : 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    'odt' : 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
    'oga' : 'audio/ogg',
    'ogv' : 'video/ogg',
    'ogx' : 'application/ogg',
    'otf' : 'font/otf',
    'png' : 'image/png',
    'pdf' : 'application/pdf',
    'ppt' : 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
    'pptx' : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
    'rar' : 'application/x-rar-compressed',
    'rtf' : 'application/rtf',
    'sh' : 'application/x-sh',
    'svg' : 'image/svg+xml',
    'swf' : 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
    'tar' : 'application/x-tar',
    'tif' : 'image/tiff',
    'tiff' : 'image/tiff',
    'ttf' : 'font/ttf',
    'txt' : 'text/plain',
    'vsd' : 'application/vnd.visio',
    'wav' : 'audio/wav',
    'weba' : 'audio/webm',
    'webm' : 'video/webm',
    'webp' : 'image/webp',
    'woff' : 'font/woff',
    'woff2' : 'font/woff2',
    'xhtml' : 'application/xhtml+xml',
    'xls' : 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'xlsx' : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'xml' : 'application/xml&nbsp;',
    'xul' : 'application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml',
    'zip' : 'application/zip',
    '3gp' : 'video/3gpp',
    '3g2' : 'video/3gpp2',
    '7z' : 'application/x-7z-compressed' 
};
```

- Later imported this in my provider file and made a method to have this available application wide.

**APIService.ts:**

```
import { FILE_EXTENSION_HEADERS } from './file_extension_headers';


@Injectable()
export class APIService{
  /* some other methods */

    fetchFileHeader(extension){
        extension = extension.toLowerCase();
        return FILE_EXTENSION_HEADERS[extension] !== undefined ? FILE_EXTENSION_HEADERS[extension] : 'text/plain';// default if no appropriate header is found
    }
}
```

- **Note that** it is still quite possible that sending appropriate header might not open the file. In this case, you will need to have appropriate application installed on your mobile devices to open such kind of files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the after the **file:///** because after the **sdk 16** it only accept ***without file:/// path***

```
let path = "your path (file:///storage/emulated/0/)"; 
let tempVal = path.split('///');

this.fileOpener.open(tempVal[1] + this.qrImgName + '.jpg', 'image/jpeg')
  .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
```

here, **tempval** containes the path after the "file:///" so it's look like ***storage/emulated/0/*** and **qrImgName** is the variable that contains image name that you actully want to open.

so at the end the open url look like ***"storage/emulated/0/imagename.jpg"***